# Flutter Bluetooth thermal POS printer

Tags: flutter, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer, pos

Is there any way that I can print a receipt on a Bluetooth thermal printer, as I really struggling finding the solution on flutter? Anything could help, I really appreciate those answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you need to write your own logic using Bluetooth packages.
There is package available which currently supports WiFi POS printer.
Take a look
https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/esc_pos_printer

Comment: Will this package also work for star printers?

Comment: I'd say you have to give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

I have tried `esc_pos_bluetooth` package and it's not working for Bixolon bluetooth printer.

I'v found `blue_thermal_printer` library and it worked for me on Android but this library doesn't support iOS until now:
https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this package: `esc_pos_bluetooth`(https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_bluetooth)?

Answer (score 1):

Not much luck on my end either (on ios). Unfortunately, `esc_pos_bluetooth` doesn't detect my Epson TM-T88VI so that's a little bit of a road block...

Answer (score 0):

There are three major bluetooth printing plugins, i have tried them all and so far this package is the best one esc_pos_bluetooth is the best on my case.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful Flutter SDKs for Thermal Printer:

- [bluetooth_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_thermal_printer) - This is a Flutter plugin that allows you to use a Bluetooth thermal printer on Android device.
- [blue_print_pos](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_print_pos) - This is a Flutter plugin that enables you to use a
  POS (point of sale) system on both Android and iOS device.
  This is the updated forked [blue_print_pos SDK](https://github.com/ankush-ppie/blue_print_pos/) which I used in Dec, 2022. You can use it without facing any issues.

How to integrate SDK: [Detailed Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70537038/flutter-bluetooth-thermal-printer-integration/74911755#74911755)