# flutter print ticket withturkish characters

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get a printout from the thermal printer in flutter, but the Turkish characters are incorrect (unreadable)
I used the blue_thermal package and I cannot change the font family in this package.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem with arabic character & tried lots of packages and found some useful Flutter SDKs for Thermal Printer which provides support for multiple languages:

- [bluetooth_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_thermal_printer) - This is a Flutter plugin that allows you to use a Bluetooth thermal printer on Android device.
- [blue_print_pos](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_print_pos) - This is a Flutter plugin that enables you to use a POS (point of sale) system on both Android and iOS device.
  This is the updated forked [blue_print_pos SDK](https://github.com/ankush-ppie/blue_print_pos/) which I used in Dec, 2022. You can use it without facing any issues.

It will help in integrate SDK: [Detailed Stackoverflow Answer on how to integrate printer SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70537038/flutter-bluetooth-thermal-printer-integration/74911755#74911755)

Hope it will works for you.

Comment: Let me know if it is not working. I'll provide solution on Monday.

Comment: I can say that there is no package that I have not tried.
I also tried the suggested packages. Characters are not read when printed. After so many tries, my finding is there is a problem with the font. Nor can I find a package that can change the font.

import 'package:bluetooth_print/bluetooth_print.dart';
import 'package:bluetooth_print/bluetooth_print_model.dart';
And
import 'package:blue_thermal_printer/blue_thermal_printer.dart';

I'm printing in these two packages, but I can't because they both don't support fonts.